# packet capture for real time integration

Tags: mqtt, packet, tcpdump, tshark

I need to capture packets and use the data for a real time integration.

The packets flow between two legacy systems which provide no other means of accessing the data.

This appears simple to do using tcpdump or tshark, but I am unable to find a streamlined way to get the data off the capture device (raspberry pi) and to the service that manages the integration. As far as I can see from documentation, tcpdump and tshark only write to files or the console.

Ideally, the data in each packet would be sent from the capture device to a remote MQTT topic. This would avoid the write and file parsing that are inherent to tcpdump/tshark. I get that I can extract the data from a file, but I am looking to eliminate that step. The packet traffic that will be captured is low volume (max one packet per second).  Am I missing something that would do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

Tcpdump and wire/tshark both make use of the pcap (libpcap) library to do the actual packet capture and to process rules to decide which packets to keep.

Your best bet will be to write a small application that uses this and a MQTT client library to capture and forward the packets you want

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is exactly what I want to avoid, however. Neither tool has any output options other than libpcap? And there is no other tool with more flexibility? Seems limiting that there isnt a way to avoid I/O for a use case like this.

Comment: There would be no disk IO in what I've described, you read directly from libpcap and write directly to MQTT, there are wrappers for any number of languages for libpcap and MQTT libraries for as many, running this up with something like node-pcap would be the matter of minutes...